# Converting HTML to PDF using iText on Android. How to set UTF-8 (diacritics)?

Tags: java, android, pdf, itext

### I am trying the following

itextg 5.5.3 jar

xmlworker 5.5.3 jar

---

*test.html*

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="cs">
<head>
</head>
<body>
Test: ěščřžýáíé Ň ň ě Ě

<div style="font-family: 'Times New Roman',font-weight: bold,backround-color blue;">
  Test: ěščřžýáíé Ň ň ě Ě
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

*ConvertHTMLToPDF.java*

```
public class ConvertHTMLToPDF {

    public static final String RESULT = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/test.pdf";
    public static final String RESORCE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/Notes/html/test.html";


        void convertHTMLToPDF() throws IOException, DocumentException {

            Rectangle pagesize = new Rectangle(415,1750);
            Document document = new Document(pagesize);

            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream(RESULT));

            document.open();

            XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document, new FileInputStream(RESORCE));

            document.close();
            System.out.println( "PDF Created!" );
        }
    }
```

Output *test.pdf*

- Test: šžýáíé
- Test: šžýáíé

---

**How to get *test.pdf***

```
 Test: ěščřžýáíé Ň ň ě Ě
 Test: ěščřžýáíé Ň ň ě Ě
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Please take a look at the XML Worker examples: http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/

**Example 1:** [D07_ParseHtmlAsian](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D07_ParseHtmlAsian)

Tell the `parseHtml()` method that you're reading the XML as UTF-8:

```
XMLWorkerHelper.getInstance().parseXHtml(writer, document,
    new FileInputStream(HTML), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

**Example 2:** [D07bis_ParseHtmlAsian](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D07bis_ParseHtmlAsian)

Tell the `parse()` method that you're reading the XML as UTF-8:

```
XMLWorker worker = new XMLWorker(css, true);
XMLParser p = new XMLParser(worker);
p.parse(new FileInputStream(HTML), Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
```

Note that you'll prefer this in favor of example 1 when you want to control the fonts that are being used to output the PDF. Please compare with [D07tris_ParseHtmlAsian](http://itextpdf.com/sandbox/xmlworker/D07tris_ParseHtmlAsian).